# How to add JS/CSS Cdn into a website in MVC Core?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core, .net-core, cdn

How do I add CSS CDN Font always in a MVC Core project?

I tried adding the following link from FontAlways into the top of the view Index.cshtml view.
It does not work. I should see the Down Arrow icon.
Should I add to site.css, add a separate library?

**Index.cshtml**

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d14c565c21.js"></script>


<!--Accordion wrapper-->
<div class="accordion md-accordion" id="accordionEx" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

  <!-- Accordion card -->
  <div class="card">

    <!-- Card header -->
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne1">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx" href="#collapseOne1" aria-expanded="true"
        aria-controls="collapseOne1">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          Collapsible Group Item #1 <i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i>
        </h5>
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Card body -->
    <div id="collapseOne1" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne1"
      data-parent="#accordionEx">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3
        wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum
        eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla
        assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred
        nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer
        farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
        labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- Accordion card -->

  <!-- Accordion card -->
  <div class="card">

    <!-- Card header -->
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo2">
      <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx" href="#collapseTwo2"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo2">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          Collapsible Group Item #2 <i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i>
        </h5>
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Card body -->
    <div id="collapseTwo2" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo2"
      data-parent="#accordionEx">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3
        wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum
        eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla
        assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred
        nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer
        farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
        labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- Accordion card -->

  <!-- Accordion card -->
  <div class="card">

    <!-- Card header -->
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree3">
      <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx" href="#collapseThree3"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree3">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          Collapsible Group Item #3 <i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i>
        </h5>
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Card body -->
    <div id="collapseThree3" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree3"
      data-parent="#accordionEx">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3
        wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum
        eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla
        assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred
        nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer
        farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
        labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- Accordion card -->

</div>
<!-- Accordion wrapper -->
```

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/javascript/accordion/

[image: Icons from Font Always]

Answer (score 1):

You don't add something like this to a view like `Index.cshtml`. You add it to your layout (`Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml` or `Pages\Shared\_Layout.cshtml`, depending on whether you're using MVC or Razor Pages), in the `<head>` tag.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
  ...
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d14c565c21.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your CDN link is not correct.Try to register [Font Awesome Account](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/get-started/) + Kit and use the generated Kit's code in `<head></head>` of `_layout.cshtml`

```
<html>
  <head>
   <!-- Place your kit's code here -->
   <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f2e77270f1.js"></script>
  </head>

</html>
```